# Delayng a function call in angular/typescript project

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a page in my angular project that has a formulary with a submit button to send the client data to my database, but after a send the data i want to delete the client from the client's table and insert his info to another table. The problem is the client first insert uses the client id from the  table im deleting his data. It happens at the same time and because they are both in the same button click event. How can should i make the delete function call wait till the insert one is deployed?

This is the button which submits and deletes

```
  <button ion-button full block color="danger"(click)="postDados(form.controls.itemRows);postNeurosensi(formsensi.controls.itemRows3);postEletroneuro(form2.controls.itemRows2);deletaDados()">Enviar</button>
```

This are the functions at the Page.TS file.

```
 postEletroneuro(req){
    this.service.postEletroneuro(req.value)
    .subscribe(
      data => console.log(data.message),
      err => console.log(err)

   );  
  }
  deletaDados(){ 

    this.service.deleteData(this.parametroid).subscribe(
      data => {
        console.log(data.message);
        this.getDados();
      }

      ,
      err => console.log(err)
    );      

  }
```

And now the service.ts functions

```
postEletroneuro(params){
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-type','application/json');
    return this.http.post(`${this.api}eletroneuro/`,params,{
      headers: headers
  }).map(
    (res:Response) => {return res.json();}
  );

  }

  deleteData(id){
    console.log(`${this.api}${id}`)
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-type','application/json');
    return this.http.post(`${this.api}fichasdia/${id}/`,id,{
      headers: headers
  }).map(
    (res:Response) => {return res.json();}
  );
  }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I can't follow that's something the server can handle on it's own or not?

Comment: Instead of putting all function inside (click) event cant you call the consecutive function at the end of the current executing function??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
postEletroneuro(req){
    this.service.postEletroneuro(req.value)
    .subscribe(
      data => {
         console.log(data.message);
         deletaDados();
      },
      err => console.log(err)

   );  
  }
  deletaDados(){ 

    this.service.deleteData(this.parametroid).subscribe(
      data => {
        console.log(data.message);
        this.getDados();
      }

      ,
      err => console.log(err)
    );      

  }
```

And call (without deletaDados):

```
<button ion-button full block color="danger"(click)="postDados(form.controls.itemRows);postNeurosensi(formsensi.controls.itemRows3);postEletroneuro(form2.controls.itemRows2);">Enviar</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this :

```
<button ion-button full block color="danger" (click)="postEletroneuro(form2.controls.itemRows2)">Enviar</button>
```

**component.ts**

```
postEletroneuro(req) {
    this.service.postEletroneuro(req.value)
        .flatMap((data) => {
            console.log("data", data);
            return this.service.deleteData(this.parametroid);
        })
        .subscribe((deleteRsp) => {
             console.log("deleteRsp", deleteRsp);
        })
}
```